# Can you use the screen on a Samsung Galaxy S as camera flash for the front facing camera?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s, camera

The Samsung Galaxy S doesn't have a camera flash, are there any apps for Samsung Galaxy S to make use of the front camera and screen as a camera flash?

For a samsung galaxy s android phone.
could that work?
I couldn't find one.
it would be useful.

Comment: As this is a question and answer site, the titles of posts here should be phrased as a question, I've edited yours to change it to a question, and slightly edited your first line to make it clearer. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

Even on models that have a built-in flash, using it isn't worth your time.  Point flashes almost always make the picture look bad, especially when the camera is a crappy phone camera.  I suggest making sure the subject is well-lit instead.  That all said, the screen isn't bright enough for a flash.  Best case it would provide a little "ambient" lighting in a dark room and you'd have to take the picture up close.

Comment: ...and would suck your battery dry.

Comment: It depends on why you're taking photos; flashes look awful compared to a well setup and lit scene, but they're used in different situations. I've found a flash (on a compact camera or a phone) invaluable for capturing candid moments of friends at parties or in bars, these are situations where you don't have the time or control of the situation to sort out lighting, a flash lets you get a picture *now* and be able to actually see the subjects instead of a collection of dark blurs. I actually thought this question sounded like a clever way to get round a hardware limitation, I'm interested in it

Comment: @GAThrawn: Sure, but wouldn't you want to use the rear-facing camera in those instances?